# Looking for an AC socket that mounts to a PCB

Tags: pcb-design, ac, connector

I'm looking for an AC socket (U.S.) that mounts vertically (not right-angle) to a PCB for a smart power strip project. It should have through-hole or tabbed connections that I can solder into slots or holes in the PCB. I've been looking on Digikey/Mouser/Google for about an hour now and I'm almost convinced they don't exist. Am I using the wrong keywords? Has anyone seen such a connector?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I went to mouser's  "AC Power Plugs & Receptacles" page and selected 15A and Through-hole mount and got 3 results from AMP/Tyco